# Can two players play non-simultaneously?

Tags: civilization-5

My fiancee and I are trying to find a game that we can play together, and neither one of us is a strategy fan. The whole sandboxy aspect of Civ seemed like it might be a nice way to get our feet wet. The one issue is we tend to have conflicting schedules.

Is it possible to start a two player game, make a turn, then log out. Then she can log in, make her turn, and log out. Sort of like one would do with games like "Chess with friends"?

Or does it require that we both sit down and play a game from beginning to end? Can't seem to find an answer to this. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure if that would be fun. Depending on the size of the map and how aggressively (militaristically speaking) you play, a game of Civ could take a *very* long time...

Comment: Note the new answer at the bottom of the linked question - Giant Multiplayer Robot has gotten some recent press about its ability to automate hotseat games.